# Valor máximo de una cola

Tags: python, pilas, spyder

Dada la clase `Queue` implementar un método `maximo` que no reciba ningún parámetro y que devuelva el valor máximo almacenado en la cola. Si la cola está vacía, devolverá `None`.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, next=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next


class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._head = None
        self._last = None
        self._size = 0

    def enqueue(self,value):
        newnode = Node(value)
        if self._head is None:
            self._head = newnode
        else:
            self._last.next = newnode
        self._last = newnode
        self._size += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            raise IndexError("dequeue from empty queue")
        returned = self._head.value
        self._head = self._head.next
        if self._head is None:
            self._last = None
        self._size -= 1
        return returned
```

Mi código :

```
def maximo(self):
    if len(self._head(value) > self._last(value)) :
        return value
    else :
        None
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def maximo(self):
    if len(self._head(value) > self._last(value)) :
        return value
    else:
        None
```

ese codigo solo comparara los ultimos 2, no conozco la clase nodo, pero esto `self._head` es un nodo y ya esta instanciado, entonces para obtener si valor seria algo como `self._head.value`, entonces para saber el maximo seria algo asi:

```
def maximo(self):
    temp=self._head #nodo temporal
    maxNodo=self._head #nodo maximo
    while(temp!=self._last):
        if (temp.value>maxNodo.value):
            pass #aqui debe ir algo
        #aca debe ir como avanzar
```

espero que el codigo le ayude a entender un poco como solucionar el problema

Answer (score 0):

No dices cómo está definido `Node`, por lo que voy a suponer que está definido así:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Node:
    value: int
    next = None
```

Se puede redefinir la clase para añadirle la propiedad `empty`:

```py
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self._head = self._last = None
        self.size = 0

    @property
    def empty(self):
        return self.size == 0

    def enqueue(self, value):
        newnode = Node(value)
        if self.empty:
            self._head = newnode
        else:
            self._last.next = newnode
        self._last = newnode
        self.size += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.empty:
            return None
        else:
            value = self._head.value
            self._head = self._head.next
            self.size -= 1
            return value
```

Añadimos el método máximo según los requisitos:

```py
    def maximo(self):
        if self.empty:
            return None
        else:
            maxvalue = self._head.value
            head = self._head
            while head.next is not None:
                head = head.next
                maxvalue = max(maxvalue, head.value)
            return maxvalue
```

Pero siendo más prácticos, sería mejor crear un método que nos devolviera un iterador con los valores de la cola, con el que la implementación del máximo y otras funciones resultaría trivial:

```py
    def items(self):
        head = self._head
        while head is not None:
            yield head.value
            head = head.next

    def maximo(self):
        return None if self.empty else max(self.items())
```

Comment: Añadí la clase ```node```